# Dependency issue with conda, pip and virtualenv

Tags: pip, virtualenv, conda

I am using `conda(anaconda 2)`. Before installing `anaconda`, my Ubuntu16.04 already had `pip` installed. I recently installed `virtualenv` using `pip  install virtualenv`. I did the following steps while trying to install `coala` in my virtual environment.

1. Create a new virtual environment using `virtualenv venv`
2. Activate environment using `source activate path/to/activate`
3. Clone the `coala` repository.
4. Run `pip3 install -e .` while inside the repository

After all this, I get the following error from `coala`:

```
 There is a conflict in the version of a dependency you have installed and the requirements of coala. This may be resolved by creating a separate virtual environment for coala or running `pip install "yapf~=0.14.0"`. Be aware that the latter solution might break other python packages that depend on the currently installed version.
```

I am already in a `virtualenv`, so I tried installing `yapf` as per the command: `pip install "yapf~=0.14.0"`. After that, when I check my `pip list`, it still showed `yapf (0.15.2)`, To solve this, I did:

1. `pip uninstall yapf`
2. `pip install "yapf~=0.14.0"`

Now when I check my `pip list`, I get the desired results. BUT, the error is still there. It still shows the same dependency error. I am unable to understand what is happening? Which `pip` is installing what and where, what is `conda` doing behind the scenes, how is `virtualenv` behaving with `conda`, and the most important, why this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: You should not mix `virtualenv` and conda environments - they are very different things. What is the value of your `$PATH`?

Comment: @darthbith yeah, I uninstalled `conda` and used `virtualenv` for stuff to work. `conda` breaks everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, what I found out was that `conda` and `virtualenv` do not go hand in hand. `condas` has the ability to create it's own virtual environment, and if using `condas`, we must create a `conda` virtual environment(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26733971/4554700) answer).

What I did was uninstalled `conda` and make a virtual environment using `virtualenv`. What I could have done as well is uninstall `virtualenv` and create `condas` environment and work in that.

Answer (score 0):

first create a virtualenv pertaining to python3.x

template

```
virtualenv -p {location of python3 version } {name of virtualenv folder}
```

like this

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 venv
```

then activate it

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

then run

pip install {library you want to use}

```
pip install "yapf~=0.14.0"
```

This should install yapf into the venv folder.

try that let us know.

Comment: `virtualenv` and `condas` are entirely different. I don't think would work. I had to delete `condas` to make it work. Thanks anyways. :)